# SolrJ Query

Tags: solr

Hallo everyone,

i have to query multiple values against an index (just like a IN (id1, id2, id3) sql query )
using SolrJ, in other words i want to retrieve docs which field matches with  a set of values.

As solrj api is rough documented i expect someone could help me

Regards

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery().setQuery("myField:id1 OR myField:id2 OR myField:id3");
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(solrQuery);
```

or:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery().setQuery("myField:(id1 OR id2 OR id3)");
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(solrQuery);
```

Comment: riggt, it's my fault i haven't explain the question well.

What i want to do it's to implement same functionality avoiding OR -- OR .. OR (the solr query isn't implement it? )

thx

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on the solr-user mailing list

Answer (score 0):

In the schema definition file conf/schema.xml you can specify the default operator, make sure it is an OR:

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

Then you can separate words by spaces in your query and this will lead to an OR of the words:

```
solrQuery.setQuery("myField:(id1 id2 id3)")
```

Comment: Note that it's not recommended to rely on this setting as it's being considered for deprecation: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#line-118

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and in `Solr 5` this one seems to work well:

```
String mQueryString="term:business OR term:\"information security\"";
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(mQueryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Day ,

You could do that by 2 way

1- Using **OR** as separator between values we can use StringUtils to make it easier check below

```
Set<String> pdfFamilies = new HashSet<String>();
String familyIdsString = StringUtils.join(pdfFamilies , 'OR');
solrQuery = new SolrQuery("FAM_ID: ( " + familyIdsString + " )");
```

2-Using **SPACE** as separator between values check below

```
Set<String> pdfFamilies = new HashSet<String>();
String familyIdsString = StringUtils.join(pdfFamilies , ' ');
solrQuery = new SolrQuery("FAM_ID: ( " + familyIdsString + " )");
```